# Fixed axis in Excel chart

Tags: excel, charts

Per default, Excel changes the axis to fit the data. I want to set a fixed x-axis on my chart, e.g. from 0 to 2.

This is to avoid the disturbing resizing shown in the gif below:

[image]

I'm using Office 365 Home. I've looked for this setting, but simply can't find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try right clicking on the axis, select format axis then you should get a menu on the right to set the maximum value of the axis. See the screenshots below.

Format axis:

[image]

Set the maximum value to 2.

[image]

Comment: When a number is entered, the "Auto" disappears